# 128gb SD card, Unable to install raspbian, nextcloudPi, or dietPi

Tags: raspbian, nextcloud

My goal: I am trying to get raspberry pi to work with nextcloud on a 128gb sd card.

I have tried everything so far from raspbian lite, nextcloudPi, and dietPi.
I was able to get dietPi and nextcloud to work with my 4gb sd card. 
I bought a 128sd card becuse its faster, i did not take into account that i have the first raspberry pi not 2 or 3 just the first version. 
Not sure if that is why it is failing.

When i try raspbin it fails to even get to the login, it trys to resize it on almost all installs due to how big my sd card is. Red light comes on on the raspberry pi, i think it means it cant read the sd card when it comes on after that it just freezes.

I have been using etcher to format the sd card with the disk image of dietPi/nextcloudPi/Raspbian. All failed. My guess is that the first gen of raspberry pi cannot handle the new tech of a 128gb card or something is wrong that i need to do manually.

Comment: Although not an answer to your question, the speed of access to an SD card depends upon two things: the "speed class" of the SD card, and the circuit within the Pi to which the SD card is attached.  I've found C10 SD cards (10 Mb/sec) to be "fast enough."  There's a nice table of speed classes here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SD_card#Class  Someone else will need to discuss the transfer speeds the Pi can support.  Beyond the speed the Pi will support, faster SD cards will not improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

According to the following, large sd cards must be formatted as FAT32:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/sdxc_formatting.md

You won’t be able to use Etcher or an other imaging tools as these will overwrite the FAT32 formatting with whatever format was used in the image. You would have to copy NOOBS onto the SD Card.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it **will NOT** be faster on the Pi (I could go into the technical reasons).

There is no reason you could not install any OS. If you are starting with NOOBS you need to format FAT32 first.